# Could shared hosting be the cause of being logged out of Flask app?

Tags: flask, shared-hosting, namecheap

I have a little app that uses Flask, including flask_login. When running it on my host server (apache, shared hosting on Namecheap), the user gets logged out after a brief amount of time, typically 5-30 minutes. The cookie has the expected expiration date/time (default 31 days), yet the user is still logged out. I'm not closing the browser or doing anything that should end the session. Identical code works fine locally and the user stays logged in for the expected duration. Could this be the result of some quirk with the hosting provider?

Comment: How are you setting the app's secret key.  Please show code.

Comment: @v25 You sly boots. I was randomly generating the key at app startup, and apparently my hosting provider restarts the app all the time. So using a constant value solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, boom.  I've seen some posts on here where people do something like `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(48)` not realising that this generates a new key on each app restart.  I was expecting something like this.  Of course another issue there is the use of `urandom` when in-fact the [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) should be used when automating the generation of this key, but I digress :)